# Finding the rate of decrease in height from a ration

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given this problem:

[image]

So I have this ratio:

$$x:y$$
$$11:5$$

So I figured the angle of descent must be

$$\arctan(5/11) = 24.44 degrees$$

So I am told that she is traveling at 30 miles per hour. So I am going to try to find the y component of that to figure out the rate at which y decreases. First I am going to convert 30mph to 30miles/second

$$(30/3600) * 5280 = 44ft/s$$

So to find the y descent rate:

$$44\sin(24.44) = 18.22ft/s$$

So my equation would be:

$$d(t) = -18.22t + 11000$$

However, none of the options display that option. What am I calculating incorrectly?

The book explains you get the answer by doing the following:

$$44ft * \frac{5}{11} = 20ft$$
$$m = -20$$
$$b = 11000$$
$$d(t)=mt + b= -20t + 11000$$

But why do they multiply 44ft by 5/11?

Comment: you are getting exacting results you want an estimate not the exact result. also 36000 should be 3600 just a typo though.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Fixed that type. Updated the post. I don't think being exact should be a problem. I added to my edit the explanation the book provides

Comment: the multiply by ${5\over 11}$ is scaling I believe.  I solved it to your solution this way:

$$\sqrt{11^2+5^2}=12.08\ldots\\{44\over 12.08\ldots}=3.64\ldots\\(3.64\ldots) \cdot 5 =18.20\ldots\\18.20\ldots \approx 20\therefore C$$

Comment: see the question it is asking for a close estimate not an exact answer.